# Is this histogram left-skewed or right-skewed, or symmetric?

Tags: statistics

I know the question seems fairly simple, and the solution probably is. I figure the data is right skewed because most of the data is on the left. Also because there is an outlier on the right side?

(Image removed because I'm happy with the answers provided and I don't want anyone from school to take my work)

Comment: This is a multimodal distribution, skewness does not really apply

Comment: Do you have a mathematical definition of skewness?  Apply it.   There is one in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness) but I would look in your book.  It sure doesn't look symmetric to the eye

Comment: Is this out of a management math book or something?  I tutored someone in this subject and I absolutely **hated** the questions out of that text.  Subjective questions, absolutely no mathematical basis except "how the distribution looked."  Yuck.

Comment: My TA at school said this is a unimodal distribution, and we typically base the skews on whether the tail is longer on the left or right side. Would there be more data on the left or right?

Comment: Since you only have 10 data points, I would say you simply don't have enough data to determine those properties. The skew is a "third-moment" property of a distgribution,and hence requires much more data to estimate accurately. Your sample is simply not large enough. The only thing that may be useful is to generate 1000 or so "bootstrap resamples" from our data and calculate the skew statistic for each. How often is it positive vs. negative? How often is it near 0 (say -0.5 to 0.5). That may help, but its hard to say anythiing really...10 points is pretty sparse.

Comment: Agreed, this is a bad question unless they're going for the, "There's not enough info to make a reasonable decision" answer.

Comment: Yeah thats exactly how i felt, the data is so sparse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Eupraxis1981, there needs to be much more data to use skewness. With 10 data points, a useful distribution can't be created and there is so little data with multiple modes that skewness is useless.